# Fuzzy String search but for objects?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, fuzzy-search

There are lots of libraries out there that provide a fuzzy string search functionality, where you can give an input string, and search for "close enough" strings.

e.g., if you enter the word `cat`, you may get:

- cat (100%)
- hat
- rat
- catt
- etc.

Is there any sort of functionality, but for objects? An algorithm which takes two objects and compares **not whether they are similar or not** (this is simple and already done), but **rather how similar** they are. How similar can be a percent from 0 to 100%, where 100% is an exact match and 0% is not similar at all, or it can be a number, like the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance where 0 would be an exact match, and the number would be the "closeness", with no upper bound.

For example, if I have an object (javascript):

```
const a = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  age: 18
}
```

If I compare it to another object:

```
const b = {
  name: 'Some random name',
  age: 5
}
```

You would get some score that wouldn't be 0. I'm not sure what value you'd get, it'd depend on what scoring system you would use (0-100% or x >= 0)

However, the result comparing a to b would be more closer, compared to comparing it to something entirely different such as:

```
const c = {
  foo: 0
}
```

Here the objects are almost not similar at all. So the score here would be worse (for 0-100%, it would be a lower number, for x>=0, it would be a higher number, than a compared to b).

Are there any existing algorithms or libraries that may achieve something like this? Especially in javascript?

I've found some libraries that may be similar to this, but with my added critique:

- https://github.com/hath995/fuzzyEqual (javascript, seems outdated and may not be efficient)
- https://github.com/intuit/fuzzy-matcher (java, seems high quality, but only for java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the objects are ultimately composed of serializable values (no class instances or functions), one option would be to stringify them and then use the same sort of "fuzzy search" algorithm on those strings:

```js
const a = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  age: 18
};
const b = {
  name: 'Some random name',
  age: 5
};
const c = {
  foo: 0
};

// https://gist.github.com/andrei-m/982927
const getEditDistance = ((t,n)=>{if(0==t.length)return n.length;if(0==n.length)return t.length;var h,e,r=[];for(h=0;h<=n.length;h++)r[h]=[h];for(e=0;e<=t.length;e++)r[0][e]=e;for(h=1;h<=n.length;h++)for(e=1;e<=t.length;e++)n.charAt(h-1)==t.charAt(e-1)?r[h][e]=r[h-1][e-1]:r[h][e]=Math.min(r[h-1][e-1]+1,Math.min(r[h][e-1]+1,r[h-1][e]+1));return r[n.length][t.length]});
const diff = (obj1, obj2) => {
  const str1 = JSON.stringify(obj1);
  const str2 = JSON.stringify(obj2);
  const dist = getEditDistance(str1, str2);
  const peakDist = Math.max(str1.length, str2.length);
  return (peakDist - dist) / peakDist;
}
console.log(diff(b, b));
console.log(diff(b, a));
console.log(diff(b, c));
```

If you want to compare *object shapes* only, but not the underlying values, you can use a replacer function when invoking `JSON.stringify` to replace all primitive values with the empty string. For example, both your `a` and `b` objects will become `{"name":"","age":""}`, but your `c` object will become `{"foo":""}`.

```js
const a = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  age: 18
};
const b = {
  name: 'Some random name',
  age: 5
};
const c = {
  foo: 0
};

// https://gist.github.com/andrei-m/982927
const getEditDistance = ((t,n)=>{if(0==t.length)return n.length;if(0==n.length)return t.length;var h,e,r=[];for(h=0;h<=n.length;h++)r[h]=[h];for(e=0;e<=t.length;e++)r[0][e]=e;for(h=1;h<=n.length;h++)for(e=1;e<=t.length;e++)n.charAt(h-1)==t.charAt(e-1)?r[h][e]=r[h-1][e-1]:r[h][e]=Math.min(r[h-1][e-1]+1,Math.min(r[h][e-1]+1,r[h-1][e]+1));return r[n.length][t.length]});
const stringify = obj => JSON.stringify(obj, (key, val) => (
  typeof val === 'object' && val !== null
    ? val
    : ''
));
const diff = (obj1, obj2) => {
  const str1 = stringify(obj1);
  const str2 = stringify(obj2);
  const dist = getEditDistance(str1, str2);
  const peakDist = Math.max(str1.length, str2.length);
  return (peakDist - dist) / peakDist;
}
console.log(diff(b, b));
console.log(diff(b, a));
console.log(diff(b, c));
```

Comment: I figured that for my use case, this should be good enough as a starting point. I plan to use some of the function, especially the relative distance, and make a custom function that uses the levenshtein distance to compare fields that are the same.